# Entity Data Model Connection not Syncing properly over Git

Tags: git, entity-framework, azure

I'm working on an ASP.NET w/ MVC5 project. The project has a small and simple SQL Server Connection hosted in Azure with a single Table. For my interface I generated an EDM object using the Database as the source via "Add ADO.NET Entity Data Model"

It all worked fine until I tried to work on the project on another machine. I synced the project to the other machine via GitHub, and everything was there (including the connection to my Azure hosted SQL Server), but I couldn't get the Solution to Build.

As can be seen in the Screenshot below, the EDM and it's associated files are marked as "checked-in" with a warning icon, and there are build-warning messages telling me the files are missing. However they show up in the Solution Explorer, and I can see them in the folder when I navigate to it manually in Windows File Explorer.

[image]

[image]

Is there some other configuration step I need to take to get the model to sync properly to other machines?

Comment: Are the model files present in the folder?

Comment: @Baskar yes thats the first thing i checked. As far as I can tell the contents of that folder are Identical on both machines. I added an additional screenshot.

Comment: Can you try a clean solution and then build. Can you check if there are any special characters in those docs making it not able to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I had an old version of the EDM that had a different name on the new machine, so when it tried to connect it got confused. I wiped the repo and re-cloned it and now it works!